# How to avoid Multiple joins for better performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have 5 tables and all have dependencies so i have written this query for fetching the data and its working fine but the performance is bad so can you suggest some concepts?

```
SELECT  a.*,cg.*,c.*,qt.*,ct.* 
FROM MYB.choice_table ct 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MYB.question_table qt ON ct.questionID = qt.questionID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MYB.category_table c ON  c.categoryID = qt.categoryID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MYB.categoryGroup_table cg ON cg.categoryGroupID=c.categoryGroupID 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MYB.audit_table a ON a.auditID=cg.auditID 
WHERE a.auditID=123
```

Comment: Replace `right join` to `inner join` where it possible

Comment: Are all the tables properly indexed?

Comment: While it's always kind of hard to read right outer joins, the query looks fine and should be quite fast. Provided of course there are constraints and indexes on all IDs as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can immediately think of is to index all the data you use for your joins.

You should also not do

```
Select *
```

Minimize the returns to what you need

**Sub Note**:

Looking at your query it is going to join the whole data set and THEN search through it for your where clause.

So let's say a.123 has only 50 values but all your tables have 10000 rows of data. You are joining n amount if tables of 10000 rows each x how ever many columns to return the search through and get 50 values

Comment: You're right. Kitchen sink queries on multiple tables are usually a mess.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have a look at the execution plan using EXPLAIN. 
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html.

Such execution plan will help you understand what is going on under the hood and identify potential issues. The join count itself isn't slowing things down.